# Wrong Number of Arguments Error in RoR App? Unsure why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I've just created a migration file, migrated it, and written my "Player" class.  I'm trying to run this code:

```
def get_most_recent_ladder
    @top_80 = Team.all
    # loop through all teams, add each player and their rating to the hash, sort by rating, limit to 200
    all_players = []

    @top_80.each do |team|
      url = "http://modules.ussquash.com/ssm/pages/leagues/Team_Information.asp?id=#{team.team_id}"
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
      player_names = doc.css('.table.table-bordered.table-striped.table-condensed')[1].css('tr td a').map(&:content)
      player_ratings = doc.css('.table.table-bordered.table-striped.table-condensed')[1].css('tr td:nth-child(4)').map(&:content)
      for i in (0..player_names.length-1)
        player = Player.create(player_names[i], player_ratings[i].to_f, team.name)
        all_players << player
      end
    end

    all_players = all_players.sort{|player1, player2| player1.rating <=> player2.rating}.reverse.first(200)
    #insert creation of ladder object with order
    @ladder = all_players
    render 'ladder'
  end
```

Unfortunately, When I run the code, Rails gives me a "Wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..2).  So a few things:

1) Here's my Player class:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :rating, :team
end
```

So it should need 3 arguments to create a new instance of the Player class.

2) I don't know why it displays "0..2" instead of a normal integer.

3) Also, I'm now getting "Uninitialized Constant PagesController::Player.

Here's the HAML layout I'm using:

```
#ladder
  %tr
    %th Player
    %th Rating
    %th Team
  %tr
    -@ladder.each do |player|
      %td player.name
      %td player.rating
      %td player.team
```

For some reason, it prints out my headings, but then literally prints out "player.name", "player.rating", "player.team" over and over again instead of each player's actual name, rating, and team...

Thoughts?

Pretty confused so any help would be awesome!

Thanks,
Mariogs

Comment: The `0..2` means the method in question was expecting between 0 and 2 arguments, but you supplied 3.

Comment: Also, the reason it was giving you an error of "uninitialized constant error" was probably because you were running off of `irb` instead of `rails c`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `create` call. You need to supply the arguments as a hash:

```
player = Player.create(:name => player_names[i], :rating => player_ratings[i].to_f, :team => team.name)
```

This is because there is no way for Rails to know that the 3 parameters you supplied are supposed to match up to your 3 fields (and you should never assume Rails will keep the fields in that order anyway). By supplying a hash with specific keys (e.g. `:name`, `:rating`, etc.) Rails can properly match up your values with your fields.

When you want to display these values in your `.haml` files, use `=` before the items:

```
%td= player.name
%td= player.rating
%td= player.team
```

Comment: For those just learning Ruby and using 1.9 or better, the new hash notation is worth picking up first. `Player.create(name: ..., rating: ..., ...)`

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'm still getting "uninitialized constant PagesController::Player"...any ideas?

Comment: Ok, so I think I've resolved this issue except for what it prints out.  My HAML layout seems fine (I think it's ok) but it's not printing each player's info.  Instead it prints "player.name", "player.rating", "player.team" again and again.  Thoughts?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Mariogs see my update; use `= player.name`, not just `player.name`

Comment: Thanks a ton, Dylan!  So it *sorta* works now.  I get something like:Player Rating Team SLU 6 Princeton 6 Harvard 6 Columbia 6 Bates 5 Trinity 5 Trinity 5 Trinity 5 GWU 5 Brown 5 Trinity 5 Navy 5 Princeton 5 Cornell 5 Cornell 5 Cornell 5 Cornell 5 Yale 5 F&M 5...so there are no names, and the ratings are integers instead of decimals...I used :decimal data type for a player's rating so I'm a bit confused why it's displaying as an integer (i used :precision => 4).  Any idea?  Thanks again!

Comment: OK, so the team missing was a typo on my part (I set name instead of team, heh).  Any thoughts on the decimal bit?  Not sure why it's behaving that way...

Comment: You'll want to use something to format the number properly; something like `= sprintf("%0.1f", player.rating)`

Comment: Interesting, any reason why it would ignore the formatting I specified?

Comment: So that works but the numbers it gives are just the integers with as many 0's as I specify after the decimal.  Seems that it's rounding at some point?

Comment: Also, I checked out my player_ratings array and it's composed of strings.  So it's not actually 4.058, but "4.058".  I'm now calling .to_f on it, but this (strangely) seems to be lopping off the decimal portion and turning it into an integer...